# Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

Im having some issues in this part :

```
// Default error handling for all actions
  private handleError(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

Where the handleError(error) is having this issue, and presents this : "(parameter) error: any"

Cant figure this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it as,

```
 private handleError(error:any) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

Probably you want to handleError from the service, you can have a detailed handling mechanism as follows,

```
 private handleErrors(error: Response | any) {
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
```

Comment: This may fix the issue, but when using TypeScript this is a terrible practice. `error` can be typed with something more useful here.

Comment: @DiogoPinto Mark if it has helped